# Theorem? For every $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, for every $A \subseteq R$ where $A$ is finite, $\exists c\in\mathbb{R}:\forall x\in A:(f(x) = c)$.

Tags: functions, proof-verification, induction

Your mathematical sense problably twitched when you read the title, as a simple counterexample of the theorem is some one-to-one function. Where then, is the mistake in this proof?

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary.

We will prove by induction that for every $n\ge 1$,  $(|A| = n \wedge A\subseteq\mathbb{R})\to \exists c\in\mathbb{R}:\forall x\in A:(f(x) = c)$.

Base case: let $n=1$ and $|A| = 1$ and let $a$ be the only element in A. Then since $a\in\mathbb{R}$ by definition $\exists c\in\mathbb{R}:(f(a) = c)$ and thus $\exists c \in\mathbb{R}:\forall x\in A:(f(x) = c)$.

Induction step: Suppose $n\ge 1$ and $\forall A\in P(\mathbb{R}):((|A| = n)\to \exists c\in\mathbb{R}:\forall x\in A:(f(x) = c))$. Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $|A| = n+1$. Choose some arbitrary $a_1\in A$ and let $A_1 = A\setminus\{a_1\}$. Then $|A_1| = n$ and thus there is some $c_1 \in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall x\in A_1 :(f(x) = c_1)$. All that there is left to prove is that $f(a_1) = c_1$. Let $a_2\in A$ and $a_2\neq a_1$. As before this means that there is some $c_2 \in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall x \in A_2:(f(x) = c_2)$. Let $a_3\in A$ and $a_3\neq a_1$ and $a_3\neq a_2$. Then $a_3\in A_1$ and $a_3\in A_2$, so $f(a_3) = c_1 = c_2 = f(a_3)$ , so since $ a_1\in A_2,\ f(a_1) = c_1$.

Comment: This is a common fallacy.  Your induction step doesn't work for $n=1$.

Comment: Why is that?sdas

Comment: Word of advice: you are overusing quantifiers and it makes it hard to read. Use plain English when you have compound quantifiers like this.

Comment: @АлександърГьорев Precisely the reason ajotatxe gives.  You say that $a_3\neq a_1$ and $a_3\neq a_2$.  This is impossible if $|A|=2$, i.e. $n=1$.  Wikipedia's induction article explains this with the example of "Show every horse is the same color" [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Example_of_error_in_the_inductive_step).

Comment: This is a reformulation of the horse problem in which all horses have the same color. The reason it fails is that your $n=1$ case does not imply your $n=2$ case. You can think of induction as being logically equivalent to strong induction and in that setting, it's easy to see that it fails as per above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ has exactly two elements there is no such $a_3$.